# How to do onclick event in VBA/VBScript

Tags: html, vba, vbscript

```
<td class="highlightTab" id="tabnew" style="background-color: red; color: yellow;" onmouseover="setBgColor('tabnew')" onmouseout="setHighOrgBgColor('tabnew','highlightTab')">
<a class="highlightTabLabel" onclick="parent.MainFrame.request('ref_back','')" href="Javascript:void(0)">
```

I am still trying to learn excel automation with web pages. I am trying to force the onclick using FireEvent (using both click and fireevent, but neither are working atm) and I cannot figure this out:

```
.getElementById("tabnew").Click
.getElementById("tabnew").FireEvent ("onclick")
```

Does anyone have any Ideas?  I really wish there was more documentation on html object library for use in VBScript/VBA :(

Comment: Inside of what application are you using this? Where does that javascript reference come into play? Can you use JavaScript in Excel?

Comment: I am running this using VBA/VBScript to Control IE (Eventually to pull data into excel from a webpage). The Javascript is part of a web page, and it contains the item which i need to click. The HTML above creates a tab essentially, that the user clicks. I am trying to replicate the click thru HTML OBJECT LIBRARY as a reference in Excel.  The onclick is nested inside the <TD> tags, so I am unsure how to gain control and force the onclick event, essentially.

Comment: So you want Excel to listen for a click event in IE? Did you start the IE session through your Excel instance?

Comment: no, the click isnt done through EXCEL, I create an instance of internet explorer, and I browse through intranet using the html object library. My end goal is going to be to pull data from a web page, but I have to tell the browser how to navigate to get there first.

Comment: What's on the left side of the period in `.getElementByID("tabnew").click`? Are you able to return the button? If you run this from VBA, you can step through the code and make sure you are able to correctly find the element you are trying to click.

Comment: `Set Browser = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer1`
`Set HTMLDoc2 = Browser.document.frames("top").document` 
`With HTMLDoc2` `THE GETELEMENT CODE GOES HERE`
`End With`
 Its not a "button" per se, its a table cell that has an onclick property. The onclick is nested inside the <td> tags, I am just not sure how to get to it

Comment: Try: `.getElementById("tabnew").firstChild.Click`

Comment: Wow, you need to be writing a book on this stuff. Worked perfectly! Can I ask you what the definition for "firstChild" is? Also, the web page pops up "VBSCRIPT: Microsoft Internet Explorer" window with a "Do you want to save?" question, and a YES/NO/CANCEL (some kind of javascript action). Is there a way to address that to be automatically yes? This will popup whenever navigating after making changes..

Comment: Firstchild is the first element contained within the <td> element.  Difficult to suggest how to address how to prevent the popup without seeing the code behind the page.

Comment: I understand, thanks. Does that mean that theres a possibility of SecondChild, ThirdChild, and so on if theres more elements in the TD tag? One last thing to ask as well if you dont mind, off topic, Is is possible to address buttons through .getelementsbyname and fireevent for an onclick, if ID is not available?

Comment: If there are multiple child nodes then you would more likely use `childNodes`: http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/childNodes Second part: getElementsByName (at least in IE) seems to check both Id and Name, so as long as your button is a match you should be able to find and click it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you're looking for:

document.getElementById("tabnew").attachEvent "onclick",getref("onclick")

First argument is the event ("onclick","onmouseover"... See: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vbscript/vbscript_events.htm (very bottom of page for list of events))
Second argument is a getref of the name of your sub.