# How to Set a value in dropdown list using VBScript

Tags: html, vbscript

I work in a firm where they have a website which provides the access to all our servers which are at remote location.
I have a VBScript which open the website and provide the username and passowrd to login to website and open the wesite for me.
also it clicks on some link fo me and then i need to change the value in a drop downlist which will display the 100 items(default is 10).
the issue i am unable to do so change the value from 10 to 100
i will show you the code i am using

```
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible = true
oIE.navigate "http://zzz.zz.zz:0000/zz/zz"
Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
Loop While oIE.ReadyState < 4 And oIE.Busy
oIE.Document.All.Item("username").Value = "zzzz"
WScript.Sleep 250
oIE.Document.All.Item("password").Value = "zzzzzz"
WScript.Sleep 250
oIE.Document.All.Item("login").submit
WScript.Sleep 100
oIE.navigate "http://zzz.zz.zz:0000/zz/zz/ca12/index.jsp?console.tab=Home&task.clear=1"
WScript.Sleep 10000
oIE.navigate "http://zzz.zz.zz:0000/zz/zz/ca12/index.jsp?task.tag=MyPasswordAccountsJSFTask"
WScript.Sleep 1000
For Each opt In oIE.document.getElementById("comObjsNum").Options
    If opt.Value = 100 Then
        opt.Selected = True
    Else
        opt.Selected = False
    End If
Next
```

**But i unable to change the value in the drop down list.
most likely "I dont know how to!! "**

The dropdown list has 4 options i.e : 10,25,50 & 100.

And i also get error at line number 9 when i am already logged in
the error says  : "Object Required...."

**Update : Still getting error using this code :**

```
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible = true
oIE.navigate "http://zzz.zz.zz:0000/zz/zz"
Do
   WScript.Sleep 500
 Loop While oIE.ReadyState < 4 And oIE.Busy
oIE.Document.All.Item("username").Value = "zzzz"
WScript.Sleep 250
oIE.Document.All.Item("password").Value = "zzzzzz"
WScript.Sleep 250
oIE.Document.All.Item("login").submit
WScript.Sleep 100
oIE.navigate "http://zzz.zz.zz:0000/zz/zz/ca12/index.jsp?    console.tab=Home&task.clear=1"
WScript.Sleep 10000
oIE.navigate "http://zzz.zz.zz:0000/zz/zz/ca12/index.jsp?        task.tag=MyPasswordAccountsJSFTask"
   WScript.Sleep 1000
   oIE.document.getElementById("comObjsNum").selectedIndex = 3
```

Comment: Sorry, but you should tidy your post up ... i tried but you have spurious `<br>`s in there! ... prefix each line of code with 4 spaces.

Comment: thanks for formating it :)

Comment: My pleasure! Except it wasn't me!!! So thanks for thanking me, but thanks to @Bond who's done the heavy lifting!

Comment: Find and Replace FTW!

Comment: Did you just post your actual login info? I edited it out, just in case. If so, change it immediately.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set the `selectedIndex` property of the control:

```
oIE.document.getElementById("comObjsNum").selectedIndex = 3
```

Edit:

Saw your second question. If you're already logged in, the password field likely won't exist on the page. That's probably why you're getting the error. So you may need to guard against it:

```
On Error Resume Next
oIE.Document.All.Item("password").Value = "zzzzzz"
If Err Then
    ' Already logged in. Change course of action.
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: One thing to ask, Will it fire onChange event ?

Comment: I am still unable to change the value. its showing error : Object required at that line. is it possible that the time provided to sleep i.e 1000 if exceeded will give such error ?

Comment: Hmm. That's the way to do it. Make sure you've got the right `id`. It should be `<select id="comObjsNum">`, according to your example.

Comment: I am totally newbie in case of VB but i  know some  programming basics so i dont know what to do for  ' Already logged in. Change course of action.' if it was C# i would probably execute the whole code  under if else statement to check whether the password field exists if true just navigate to the links and change the index if false do the normal ways

Comment: Here is the HTML of select Element :  <select id="comObjsNum" name="main:tableSearchResults:comObjsNum" style="white-space:nowrap;" title="Select the number of results to show per page" class="r5_table_view_options_text" onchange="javascript:_octo_jsutil_commandOptionOnChangeJSF('main','main:tableSearchResults:comObjsNum_option','main:tableSearchResults:comObjsNum');" onkeyup="javascript:_octo_jsutil_keyCheck(event,'main','main:tableSearchResults:comObjsNum_option','main:tableSearchResults:comObjsNum');">

Answer (score 2):

Haah... Found it !!
Thanks to all for responding here!!
and @bond as i suspected it didnt fire the onchange event +1 though for quick response

```
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible = true
oIE.navigate "http://zzz.zz.zz:0000/zz/zz/"
Do
WScript.Sleep 500
Loop While oIE.ReadyState < 4 And oIE.Busy
WScript.Sleep 150
oIE.Document.All.Item("username").Value = "youdontneeedtoseeit"
WScript.Sleep 100
oIE.Document.All.Item("password").Value = "nobodycares"
WScript.Sleep 150
oIE.Document.All.Item("login").submit
Do While oIE.busy 
WScript.Sleep 500
Loop
oIE.navigate "http://zzz.zz.zz:0000/zz/zz/ca12/index.jsp?console.tab=Home&task.clear=1"
Do While oIE.busy 
WScript.Sleep 500
Loop
oIE.navigate "http://zzz.zz.zz:0000/zz/zz/ca12/index.jsp?task.tag=MyPasswordAccountsJSFTask"
Do While oIE.busy 
WScript.Sleep 500 
Loop
oIE.document.getElementById("comObjsNum").selectedIndex = 3
WScript.Sleep 100
oIE.document.getElementById("comObjsNum").FireEvent ("onchange")
```

i had to use do whie loop in almost every statement bacause the site usualy takes time to open (unpredictable though)
and for the already logged in issue. i am almost there i will find it soon...
would like to thanks this link that hinted me to use the FireEvent :[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583405/how-to-do-onclick-event-in-vba-vbscript)