# Get IE to click on a LI link with VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get my code to click on a javascript li link or execute the javascript code, either one of those would solve my problem.

This is the code I have:

```
Sub submitlogin()

Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "http://blablabla/"


 While IE.busy: DoEvents: Wend
 On Error Resume Next


IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a").Item(4).Click 'doesn´t work
```

I have also tried:

```
IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "checkcontained();", "javascript" 'also not working
```

And tried:

```
 Set ObjA = IE.Document.getElementByID("foldinglist").getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
  ObjA.Click 'also not working


  End Sub
```

This is the HTML:

```
<body class="menu">
<div id="menu">
    <div align="left" id="text" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:40px; width: 200px; height: 19px;display:none;"><strong><b>[TimeS]</b></strong></div>
    <div align="left" id="idMenu" style="position:absolute;top:18px;left:7px; width: 200px; height: 19px; display:none;"></div>
<div id="treeview">
<div id="menu_d">
<ul style=""><li id="foldheader0" onClick="JavaScript: checkcontained();">time control
<ul id="foldinglist" style="DISPLAY:none;" onClick="JavaScript: checkcontained();"><li id="foldheader1" onClick="JavaScript: checkcontained();">Maintenance
<ul id="foldinglist" style="DISPLAY:none;" onClick="JavaScript: checkcontained();"><li><a href="JavaScript: chamaPagina('../../thisthat.asp', '');">admin</a></li></ul></li>
<li id="foldheader1" onClick="JavaScript: checkcontained();">Consult/Reports
<ul id="foldinglist" style="DISPLAY:none;" onClick="JavaScript: checkcontained();"><li><a href="JavaScript: chamaPagina('../../thisthat_redir.asp', '');">Demonst time</a></li></ul></li>
<li id="foldheader1" onClick="JavaScript: checkcontained();">help
<ul id="foldinglist" style="DISPLAY:none;" onClick="JavaScript: checkcontained();"><li><a href="JavaScript: chamaPagina('../thisthose.html', '');">PortariRE</a></li></ul></li>

        </ul>
        <form name="frmMenu"><input type="hidden" id="txtmaxnivel" name="txtmaxnivel" value="1" /></form>
```

I have to click (or exec) right here:

```
<ul id="foldinglist" style="DISPLAY:none;" onClick="JavaScript: checkcontained();"><li><a href="JavaScript: chamaPagina('../../thisthat_redir.asp', '');">Demonst time</a></li></ul></li>
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:java].  I have removed the tag for you.

Comment: QHarr, this did not work, it´s an expandable list on the website the "foldinglist" is only available after clicking first on "foldheader0" then, clicking here: "foldheader1". It opens cascade style... I don´t know if that makes a difference, but I did try your solution on both links (first on cascade and the one I actually want): IE.Document.getElementByID("foldinglist").Click and IE.Document.getElementByID("foldinglist").Click but no success

Comment: Is it an internal URL or public?

Comment: It is an internal link, on company intranet, however, there´s no URL change on the browser, so I cannot simply "IE.navigate to"

Comment: The cascade (treeview) is like this: [link](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/api)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post can help:
[How to do onclick event in VBA/VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583405/how-to-do-onclick-event-in-vba-vbscript)

However, if you try using the FireEvent, it seems to me you should use the event on the ul tag.